# azk - How to increase a VM memory in azk?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, provisioning, azk

I am trying to increase the memory of VM into AZK. Is there  some enviroment variable for do that? Can someone help me please?

`azk` (http://azk.io/)

Answer (score 6):

The amount of memory must be set before starting `azk agent`. So, be sure the agent is down and run:

```
export AZK_VM_MEMORY=[memory size in MB]
azk agent start
```

As a shorthand, you can put the `export` command into your `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file (depending on the shell you are using) to make that config persistent between different terminal sessions.

Note: by default, **azk** uses `1/6` of the total memory (or `512MB`,  whichever is greater) for the VM